# Modifying XML elements with c#

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq, ado.net

So, I have a problem to modify my XML-document. Here is my XML

```
<CookBook>
  <Recipe id="1">
    <Title>Best recipe</Title>
    <Category>...</Category>
    <Description>Some text</Description>
    <Amount>10</Amount>
    <Ingredient>
      <li>Ingredient 1</li>
      <li>Ingredient 2</li>
    </Ingredient>
    <RecipeText>
      <li>Step 1</li>
      <li>Step 2</li>
      <li>Step 3</li>
    </RecipeText>
  </Recipe>
  <Recipe id="2">
    <Title>Best recipe2</Title>
    <Category>...</Category>
    <Description>Some text</Description>
    <Amount>10</Amount>
    <Ingredient>
      <li>Ingredient 1</li>
      <li>Ingredient 2</li>
      <li>Ingredient 3</li>
    </Ingredient>
    <RecipeText>
      <li>heat the oven</li>
      <li>Do something</li>
      <li>Do something</li>
    </RecipeText>
  </Recipe>
 </CookBook>
```

So I need to update specific recipe’s li elements which are inside of Ingredient element. But I really don't  know how... I have an ingredients list, which contains values that I want to my XML.

```
foreach (var item in lvAddIngredient.Items)
      {
          string text = item.ToString();
          ingredients.Add(text);
       }
```

When I create a new Recipe I use this code

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("recipeXML.xml");
            var newElement = new XElement("Recipe", new XAttribute("id", id.ToString()),
                new XElement("Title", txtTitle.Text),
                new XElement("Category", selectedCategory.ToString()),
                new XElement("Description", txtDescription.Text),
                new XElement("Amount", txtAmount.Text),
                new XElement("Ingredient", ingredients.Select(text => new XElement("li", text))),
                new XElement("RecipeText", recipeText.Select(text => new XElement("li", text))));
            doc.Element("CookBook").Add(newElement);
            doc.Save("recipeXML.xml");
```

But I don't know how to update these li elements value. I have tried something like this, but the syntax is wrong.

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("recipeXML.xml");
string id = lbRecipes.SelectedValue.ToString();
var items = from item in xdoc.Descendants("Recipe")
            where item.Attribute("id").Value == id
            select item;
foreach (XElement ele in items)
{
    ele.SetElementValue("Title", txtTitle.Text);
    ele.SetElementValue("Category",cbAddCategory.Text);
    ele.SetElementValue("Amount", txtAmount.Text);
    ele.SetElementValue("Description", txtDescription.Text);
    ele.SetElementValue("Ingredient", ingredients.Select(text => ele.SetElementValue("li", text)));
 }
```

Comment: When you originally create the DOM, you use `ingredients.Select(text => new XElement("li", text))` for the content of the `Ingredient` element. So why aren't you using the exact same syntax when you want to modify that element? Your questions is very unclear. Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces whatever problem you're having, along with a precise description of what that problem is: what does the code do now, and what do you want it to do instead?

Comment: List<XElement> ingrediants = ele.Element("Ingredient").Elements("li").ToList(); ingrediants[0].Value = 1234;

Answer (score 0):

Just use your row identifier "li" to get what you need with your loop.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a tree view for the XML, with the help of the tree view you can browse through the elements existing in the XML, select any value that you would like to update, serialize the tree view after updating the value and save it back to the XML file.

You can create treeview with the help of this snippet!

```
 try
        {
            treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(doc.DocumentElement.Name));
            TreeNode tNode = new TreeNode();
            tNode = treeView1.Nodes[0];
            AddNode(doc.DocumentElement, tNode);
            treeView1.Show();
        }
        catch (XmlException xmlEx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(xmlEx.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void AddNode(XmlNode inXmlNode, TreeNode inTreeNode)
    {
        XmlNode xNode;
        TreeNode tNode;
        XmlNodeList nodeList;
        int i;
        if (inXmlNode.HasChildNodes)
        {
            nodeList = inXmlNode.ChildNodes;
            for (i = 0; i <= nodeList.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                xNode = inXmlNode.ChildNodes[i];
                inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xNode.Name));
                tNode = inTreeNode.Nodes[i];
                AddNode(xNode, tNode);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            inTreeNode.Text = (inXmlNode.InnerText).Trim();
        }
```